# Linear Regression with both count and continuous zero inflated variables

Tags: multiple-regression, sas, zero-inflation

I am trying to produce a multivariate linear regression model to predict the value of a continuous variable.

I have lots of variables with potential explanatory power, some are binary (e.g. sex), some are count (e.g. number of children) and some are continuous (e.g. height). All variables are non-negative.

What I am struggling with is that where there are large volumes of legitimate zero values in some of my count variables (e.g. number of days absent) and some of my continuous variables (e.g. income for benefit claimants) I can't use a zero-inflated poisson model as not all variables are count data.

What is the best way for me to create this model without dropping these variables?

Unfortuately due to the nature of my dataset and where I work I can't disclose what I am actually trying to model or what my variables are. I am also confined to using SAS to perform the modelling.